# MQSampleMessageManager cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I’m hoping you can help me with a problem compiling  the sample program MQIVP. After downloading WebSphere MQ client for 7.1.0.6 to my windows 7 PC and adding external jar references, I’m getting the following error:

**MQSampleMessageManager messageMgr cannot be resolved to a type**

```
private MQSampleMessageManager messageMgr;
private String hostname;
private String channel = null;
private String queueMgr;
private MQQueueManager queueManager;
private String port = "-1"; // @L1C
private Hashtable properties = null; // @L1A
// An output stream writer to convert the characters to.......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using MQ v8002.

MQSampleManager class resides in the same directory as MQIVP. You need to set the CLASSPATH. I was getting the following error while compiling.

```
    MQIVP.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
      private MQSampleMessageManager messageMgr;
              ^
      symbol:   class MQSampleMessageManager
      location: class MQIVP
    MQIVP.java:94: error: cannot find symbol
        messageMgr = new MQSampleMessageManager("mqjcivp");

                     ^
  symbol:   class MQSampleMessageManager
  location: class MQIVP
2 errors
```

Setting CLASSPATH resolved the problem:

```
CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\Tools\wmqjav\samples\MQSampleMessageManager.class
```